# Android Kotlin Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, android-volley

Here is the code.
Error: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

New to json. got this exception

please help thanks!

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.search1).setOnClickListener(){

            val queue :RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
            val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, { response ->


                Log.d("Json",">>Response")

            
                try {
                    val dataArray = JSONArray(response)

                    for (i in 0 until dataArray.length()) {

                        val bookList = BookList()
                        val dataObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i)

                        bookList.add(Book(dataObject.getInt("book_id"), dataObject.getString("book_title"),
                            dataObject.getString("author_name"),dataObject.getString("cover_uri")))
                        println(bookList)

                    }


                } catch (e: Exception) {
                   
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }, { error ->
                
                Log.e("TAG", "RESPONSE IS $error")
                
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Fail to get response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            })
            queue.add(request)
        }
```

[Here is the JSON format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0xLL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to treat a JSON array as a JSON object.  You can't do that.  You're using a JSONObjectRequest to get the data.  That will take the returned response and assume its a JSON object in string form and convert it to a JSON obest (so response is a JSONObject, not a string).  But your format returns a JSON array.  Use JSONArrayRequest instead.  And then you can skip the first line in your try, because the outer most layer is already converted to a JSON object.

Although really-  I'd consider rewriting this using Retrofit and GSON.  The first library is easier to use than Volley.  The second can be combined with it, and you just need to annotate your classes correctly and conversion will be automatic.